# SELECT * FROM Not Executing

Tags: sql-server

First I executed the following query:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        UPDATE MOVIES
        SET Rating = '777'
        WHERE Title IN 
        (SELECT TOP 1 Title
           FROM MOVIES 
           ORDER BY Title DESC);
```

Then the simple query to see the change I made to the table:

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIES;
```

There are only 18 rows and 3 columns but it's been executing for 15 minutes now. Before that I cancelled and tried executing again but it just won't execute.

Comment: This actually is the textbook example of a deadlock caused by a transaction that fails to commit while another requests the same space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your BEGIN TRANSACTION is holding a lock on the table. You have to either:

- Commit it with COMMIT
- Roll it back with ROLLBACK
- Use an isolation level hint in your query, like add WITH (NOLOCK) after the MOVIES table name
- Use a different default isolation level in your database, like Read Committed Snapshot Isolation, where writers don't block readers (although you won't see data that isn't committed yet)
- Run the SELECT query from the same session as your transaction (if you're working in Management Studio, that means running the query in the same tab/window)